# Custom foreign key labels in admin

Tags: django

I have a `ContentType` foreign key field.

I have models with some `verbose_name` and I want to change this `verbose_name` just for  ContentType foreignkey dropdown in admin, no other place.

Is this possible?

```
limit = models.Q(app_label='news', model='mymodel') | models.Q(app_label='person', model='myothermodel')
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=limit)
```

Comment: I'm thinking about adding a custom widget, which will override default behaviour and replace text via regex. But I'm wondering if there are any other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the simplest way of dealing with this sort of problems with `admin` are [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

Create a proxy model for `ContentType`, update `verbose_name` and make `ForeignKey` point to that.

Comment: (updated the question a little) So, I made proxy models with updated verbose_name and put them into the limit list `limit = models.Q(app_label='news', model='mynewproxymodel')` but they don't show up in the dropdown.

Comment: Honestly I've never done this in similar setup. You need to get through the implementation I suppose.

Comment: Thank for the direction anyway.